# How to kill a terminal after completion of process

Tags: python, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am learning bash script and python for my project, I wants to Kill the terminal after completion of its execution.
I run my process on one terminal and  when I execute it it open a new terminal and do requested operation and later after completion new terminal have to be closed which is not happening.
My code is:

```
import os    
os.system(""xfce4-terminal -e 'bash -c \"./testing.sh; exec bash\"'")
```

When I run this, it will open new terminal and execute in it, and after execution "pwd" is

```
ubuntu:-/home/new$
```

Not able to send any commands to there.
After completion I want to kill the terminal, because for next execution I want to open new terminal.

I tried this it works well but don't have idea how to add in python script:

```
a=`tty`    
echo $a   
b=`tty | sed 's/\/dev//'`  
echo $b  
c=`ps aux | grep $a | grep 'bash$' | awk '{print $2}'`  
echo $c  
d= `$c | awk '{print $1}'   
kill -9 $d
```

Looking for suggestion , please guide me to get solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you opening a new terminal in the first place?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "Not able to send any commands to there.". Do you want to type commands in the terminal? Then see my answer. If you want to send commands from Python to the shell in the terminal, then you'll need a lot more.

Comment: Can you describe what you want to do, in terms of desired results? I'm thinking you're looking for the solution to a problem you needn't have.

Comment: @ThomasFenzl: testing.sh does svn update then its does system build and then it creates deb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A terminal closes when its last child process exits. This will do what I think you want:

```
os.system("xfce4-terminal -e 'bash -c \"echo hello ; /bin/bash ; exit 0\"'")
```

which I tested.

**Added in response to comment**

There is a shell script in Ubuntu `/usr/bin/usb-devices` which prints to stdout and then exits. If I run the Python

```
os.system("xfce4-terminal -e /usr/bin/usb-devices")
```

then a terminal appears, shows the output of the script and then the terminal exits. It really can't be much simpler than that.

Comment: You're exiting the last /bin/bash, not the terminal.

Comment: @ThomasFenzl "A terminal closes when its last child process exits." did you test it?

Comment: It depends on what the OP is actually trying to achieve. I read it as 'he wants the terminal to be closed', which is not happening with your answer.

Comment: Agreed. The question is ambiguous.

Comment: @msw: I have tried but it wont exit terminal after completion of command

Comment: If testing.sh does terminate then the terminal will exit for the second call under **Added* above. If the terminal is not exiting, then you are not giving sufficient information, for example the contents of testing.sh

Comment: @msw: Removed /bin/bash from your solution an dthen got the output. Thanks:)

Answer (score 4):

Let's back up and look carefully at the one main line of code you posted:

```
os.system(""xfce4-terminal -e 'bash -c \"./testing.sh; exec bash\"'")
```

What does it do?

- It uses Python to invoke a shell (`os.system`), which is usually not a great idea for a host of reasons.
- Inside that shell, it launches xfce4-terminal.
- Inside xfce4-terminal, it runs bash.  Probably xfce4-terminal runs this bash inside another bash.
- Inside this new bash, it runs testing.sh.
- Finally, for reasons unclear to me, it runs another bash.

What does the process hierarchy look like?

```
shell (whichever you use to launch this thing, likely bash)
    python
        shell (the system default, possibly bash)
            xfce4-terminal
                bash (replaced by another bash at the end, "exec bash")
                    bash
                        testing.sh
```

Do you see how crazy this looks?  Think about what you're actually trying to accomplish.  It could probably look more like this:

```
shell
    python
        testing.sh
```

How to do that?

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['./testing.sh'])
```

If you really need to launch an xfce4-terminal:

```
subprocess.check_call(['xfce4-terminal', '-e', './testing.sh'])
```

Comment: I think he wants to preload the environment and then get an interactive shell. Yes, the process tree is crazy, but without more clarity of intent or what `testing.sh` does, it's pretty hard to know.

Comment: @ John Zwinck:I had tried it before but it just open a terminal and suddenly get closed.. So i tried this.

Comment: Now you say it "suddenly got closed," but in your original question you complain that the terminal doesn't close when you want it to.  I think we need you to very, very clearly explain the actual goal you are trying to accomplish here, from the top down.  Otherwise it's going to be just more band-aids on top of kludges on top of oddities.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: With your solution when I have tried it jus pop up terminal and then closes within fraction of second.

Comment: You still aren't telling us what your actual goal is.  Nor what `testing.sh` does.

Comment: Just a note, the last call doesn't "run another bash",  it does `exec base`, so it *replaces* the bash with the `-c` option

Comment: @glennjackman: `exec bash` does run another bash.  But you're right that it replaces an existing process with that new bash.  So I'll remove that last bash from my "process hierarchy" listing, or maybe update it to "replace" the old process.

Answer (score 0):

I have Tried something like this and its working now:

```
os.system("xfce4-terminal -e 'bash -c \"./testing.sh ; sleep 20 ; exit 0\"'")
```

Thanks for the help.